# Accept only one input from the keyboard in lex

Tags: c, stdin, lex, flex-lexer

First the program asks the user to enter a string. then it calls the yylex() function and display whether the string is accepted or not. I want to stop accepting further strings from the input after I match the first input.
The code below first asks the user to input a string then prints if it's accepted or not. but this process continues until I press CTRL+D. I just want to accept only one input from the string, match it and then stop. what's wrong with my code? thanks

```
%%
^[a-z][A-Z][a-z]{1,8}$  {printf("Username Accepted");}
.*                     printf("Invalid Username");
%%

int main()
{
    printf("Enter Username: ");
    yylex();
    printf("\ndone");
}
```

Comment: Be careful of tagging.  This question has nothing to do with Apache/Adobe Flex--a UI Framework.  I retagged it to gnu-flex which is used for the lexical analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

Just read the string in by our own, then call yy_scan_string followed by yylex:

```
char myString[100];
fgets (myString, sizeof(myString), stdin);
yy_scan_string(myString);
yylex ();
```